# c# snake game list of button

Tags: c#, debugging, overwrite

I am confused with the below code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    struct movedata
    {
        public Button s;
        public Point pos;
    };
    struct snake
    {
        public Point headpos;
        public List<movedata> snob;
        public Point posfood;
    };
    int limx;
    int limy;
    List<Point> food;
    List<snake> simpan;
    snake temps;
    movedata temd;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        limx = groupBox1.Width;
        limy = groupBox1.Height;
        simpan = new List<snake>();
        temps = new snake();
        temps.posfood = new Point();
        temps.headpos = new Point();
        temps.snob = new List<movedata>();
        temd = new movedata();
        temd.s = new Button();
        temd.s.Width = 30;
        temd.s.Height = 30;
        //  temd.s.Visible = false;
        temd.pos = new Point();
        createsnake(150, 150, 4);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void refreshing()
    {
        foreach (snake a in simpan)
        {
            foreach (movedata i in a.snob)
            {
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(i.s);
                Console.WriteLine(i.s.Location.X.ToString() + " " + i.s.Location.Y.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(i.s.Text);
            }
        }
    }
    private void createsnake(int x,int y, int length)
    {
        temps.headpos = new Point(x, y);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            temd.s.Location = new Point(x, y-i*30);
            Console.WriteLine(temd.s.Location.X.ToString() + " " +temd.s.Location.Y.ToString());
            temd.pos = new Point(0, 1);
            temd.s.Text = i.ToString();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                temps.headpos = new Point(x, y);
                temd.s.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            temps.snob.Add(temd);
            foreach (movedata a in temps.snob)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.s.Location.X.ToString() + " " + a.s.Location.Y.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(a.s.Text);
            }
        }

        simpan.Add(temps);
        refreshing();
    }
}
```

I've already debugged my program and stuck with procedure `createsnake();`
this procedure only print some button.

But when I printout what in the list of button is :

```
    150 150 //1'st iteration
    150 150 // the position of the button
    0       // name of button
    150 120 //2 iteration
    150 120// begin content of list button
    1
    150 120
    1       // end
    150 90//3 iteration
    150 90 //begin position content list of button
    2      
    150 90
    2
    150 90
    2     // end
    150 60 // 4 iteration
    150 60 //begin content of position and name list of button
    3
    150 60
    3
    150 60
    3
    150 60
    3  //end
```

In the end why is it overwrite the data before it?
I suspect it is add method from list but can't get solution for.
My code before is incomplete there some unused variable just ignore it.

**Expected result**:

```
    150 150
    0
    150 120
    1
    150 90
    2
    150 60
    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `createsnake()` function you have this code

```
   foreach (movedata a in temps.snob)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.s.Location.X.ToString() + " " + a.s.Location.Y.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(a.s.Text);
    }
```

which writes the position once and then you are calling the `refreshing()` function, which also does the following

```
    foreach (movedata i in a.snob)
    {
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(i.s);
        Console.WriteLine(i.s.Location.X.ToString() + " " + i.s.Location.Y.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(i.s.Text);
    }
```

You are printing the co-ordinates twice in two different locations and that's why they are duplicating.

Comment: sory but i already tried it no matter what the 4 button is overlap in 1 place. so i don't know what the cause writeline console is just to make sure what the content of variable. the fact that when i call method add() from list. is changing the previous data.this is the core of this program problem